# Работа с массивом aiogram python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, aiogram

Написал я код минибота, изучаю массивы, разобрался как заполнять и работать через циклы
Но появилась проблема в работе массива в боте, я хочу создать массив кнопок из текст
который вводит юзер
Но мне выдается ошибка
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
И как не крутись, в боте этот массив из кнопок просто не заполняется

ОШИБКА ТУТ: `buttons[i] = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{item}', callback_data=f'{i}')`

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import Throttled
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

bot = Bot(token="")
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

class Text(StatesGroup):
    txt = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите текст: ")
    await Text.txt.set()
    @dp.message_handler(state=Text.txt)
    async def massiv(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        result = message.text.split()
        print(result)
        buttons = []
        for i, item in enumerate(result):
            print(f'Создание кнопки номер {i} с текстом {item}\n')
            buttons[i] = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{item}', callback_data=f'{i}')
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тест кнопок")
        print(buttons)
        await state.finish()
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Вы бы указывали, к какой строке ошибка выдана. Искать пришлось. И почитайте про методы добавления элементов в список. `buttons[i] = ` принципиально неверно для списка нулевой длины, как у вас. Либо список нужной размерности делайте сразу, либо увеличивайте правильно.

Answer (score 0):

решение:

```
result = message.text.split()
    print(result)
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    buttons = []
    for i, item in enumerate(result):
        print(f'Создание кнопки номер {i} с текстом {item}\n')
        num = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{item}', callback_data=f'{i}')
        buttons.insert(i, num)
    keyboard.add(*buttons)
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Тест кнопок", reply_markup=keyboard)
```